# Obj - C argument names WITH vs WITHOUT

Tags: objective-c

I'm a java programmer and learning

Obj - C function parameters

When I saw the function declaration

```
- (void) fraction: (int) n over:(int) n2;
```

and

```
- (void) fraction: (int) n :(int) n2;
```

What's difference between them? and when should i use between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method's name is `fraction:over:`.

The second method's name is `fraction::`.

Obviously, the first name is clearer. Unnamed arguments are valid but not very self-documenting. I personally never use the 2nd form.